# Upload any type of file in phonegap / cordova

Tags: jquery, cordova, phonegap-plugins, hybrid-mobile-app, intel-xdk

I am trying to upload file from Phone-gap using file transfer plugin but `FILE_URI` returns the file path in Blob 
 `blob:http%3A//localhost%3A65304/506be833-4afb-42a4-beed-01e43bc9cd64` 
 Then I used the below code to verify it and it returns error code 5.

*Jquery Code:*

```
window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(cordova.file.applicationDirectory + snapSrc, gotFile, fail);

function fail(e) {
    console.log("FileSystem Error");
    console.dir(e);
}

function gotFile(fileEntry) {

    fileEntry.file(function(file) {
        var s = "";
        s += "<b>name:</b> " + file.name + "<br/>";
        s += "<b>localURL:</b> " + file.localURL + "<br/>";
        s += "<b>type:</b> " + file.type + "<br/>";        
        document.querySelector("#status").innerHTML = s;
        console.dir(file);
    });
}
```

1. How do i find the name and type of the file.
2. How do i resolve error code 5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is solved,it worked perfectly in real device, i think the issue lies with intel xdk emulator.

Answer (score 0):

You are currently using `resolveLocalFileSystemURL` which is not correct method use `resolveLocalFileSystemURI` instead of `resolveLocalFileSystemURL`.
You can try the following method,Hope it will help you.

```
window.resolveLocalFileSystemURI(cordova.file.applicationDirectory + snapSrc,  onSuccess, fail);

function onSuccess(fileEntry) {
    console.log(fileEntry.name);
}

function fail(error) {
    console.log(error.code);
}
```

let me know if it's not working.

Comment: resolveLocalFileSystemURI is deprecated. Please call resolveLocalFileSystemURL instead.

Comment: I am using intel xdk which says "resolveLocalFileSystemURI is deprecated. Please call resolveLocalFileSystemURL instead."